# Why won't nginx restart?

Tags: nginx, putty

I don't understand how to explain this problem. I am an idiot and I don't know about computers. Here is a picture:

[image: the code]

What does this mean why can't it restart nginx?

This happened after I turned off nginx to create a standalone HTTPS certificate with certbot. When I tried to restart nginx it stopped working.

```
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
     server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, `ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    ##
```

`      # Gzip Settings

Comment: becuase your config is wrong, its saying you added a SSL cert which doesn't exist `example.tdl`, which is most likely from some tut you copy-pasted the config from, can you show us your config

Comment: @LawrenceCherone when you say config do you mean /etc/nginx/nginx.conf? Thanks for replying

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added some more information to the post

Comment: yeah, or the one you added `example.tdl` as a certificate, perhaps you were testing letsencrypt? need more details

Comment: @LawrenceCherone have edited my answer

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) - copy paste the error msg into your question. As already mentioned, the error msg tells you that the config is looking for a file in a directory path including `.../example.tdl/...`, which is probably a placeholder you copy-pasted somewhere. Find the part of the config file where that appears. Did you create real certificates, in a dir including your real domain name? If yes substitute that in place of the placeholder.